# Is there a way to hide the item tool tip when you hover over it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

I'm using a texture pack to get items that cover up player's inventory slots, but an unfortunate side effect is that you can hover over the blocked slots and still see what is there, is there any way to hide this tool tip so that it won't show?

edit, not sure if this is a command solution or a resource pack one, so i'll leave the minecraft-commands tag out

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, yes! Although quite hacky, using shaders (yes, they can fit into resource packs). Here's a link to an example (not mine): https://github.com/lolgeny/item-tooltip-remover

Answer (score -1):

No, there isnt a way to change this as this a minecraft local file hidden somewhere, if you can find, good for you! But be sure for some Java programming.